# Excel formula to compare cells on two sheets with result of third cell on 2nd sheet

Tags: excel-2010

compare 2 cells a3:B3 on raw data sheet  to 2 cells a3:b3 on sheet 1 and result is c3 from sheet 1

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [How To ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not really clear but try this, paste this in Sheet3 A1 or where you want it:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE('raw data'!A1,'raw data'!B1)=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!B1),"Same Match","No Match")
```